# Runtime for function with loop involving recursive calls

Tags: java, time-complexity

I am doing the following problem:

*Find the time complexity of the following code:*
[image]

And my thought process is as follows:

Looking at the work done inside each call to `permutation`:

`System.out.println(prefix);` would take O(n) time

`String rem = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1);` would also take O(n) time. This is because concatanating two strings takes O(m+n) time where m and n are the string lengths. Since the lengths always add up to n in this case, it would be a total of O(n).

Finally, the actual call to `permutation` (not the recursion yet) and the `str.charAt(i)` statement would be done in constant time so O(1).

However, what I am confused about is the fact that this is being done in a loop. In my book, the solution is explained as "Each node in our call tree therefore corresponds to O(n) work". Wouldn't each node take O(n+n^2)=0(n^2) work since each iteration of the loop does O(n) work and it would be called n times?

> So after thinking through this a couple times, I have decided to rephrase my question more generally, how would you go about determining the time complexity for a function of this nature in a standardized manner (a method that can be applied to most if not all problems of this nature)? Although just reasoning through the situation works, it is also prone to misconceptions (as demonstrated by me) so is there a more general way to go about this?

Comment: Heads up, the recursive call to `permutation()` does not take constant time.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I think I didn't phrase it clearly, I am just looking at the work done per node in the call tree, not considering the recursion yet

Comment: Then your analysis is correct.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I have thought about this question some more and came up with the following (in my answer below), do you mind taking a look and checking my reasoning? I do not want to proceed with any misconceived notions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after thinking through this question many times I realized that my thinking was right but only with regards to how the actual solution itself is framed. I found that you can think about this situation in two ways, keeping the following in mind.

So first, approaching this scenario, we start by looking at the work inside each call to `permutation`:

- `System.out.println(prefix);` --> O(n)
- `String rem = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1);` --> O(n)
- `permutation(rem, prefix+str.charAt(i));` --> O(1) [this is not taking recursion into account yet!!!]

So now we know the amount of work done inside each node in the overall call tree. Now we consider the recursion. There are two different ways of thinking about this.

## 1) Recursion combined with loop

Since both the loop and the recursive call result in `permutation` being called, we can simply worry about the overall number of calls to `permutation` rather than differentiating between the loop and regular recursive calls. Thus, we take an example string, let's say 'abc' and examine the call tree's leaf nodes:

1. 'abc' --> 1 node
2. 'a', 'b', 'c' --> 3 nodes
3. 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb' --> 6 nodes

Thus, we see that we have 6 leaf nodes. We can immediately see that this is equal to 3! where 3 is the length of our input string 'abc'. Thus, the amount of leaf nodes will be `n!` where `n` corresponds to input string length. The depth of the call tree will always be `n` since recursion stops when `n=0`. Thus, the total number of nodes in our call tree will be `n*n!`. Since each node corresponds to `O(n)` work, our total work done is `O(n x n x n!) = O((n + 2)!)` [we can do this because we can drop constants!].

## 2) Recursion separate from loop

Now, this is where my confusion and thus this question stemmed from. It seemed logical that the work done in each node would be `O(n^2)` rather than `O(n)` since the `for` loop is inside the node right? In this case, I was thinking of the for loop and the recursion as separate entities. But, this way of thinking is not really correct because the `for` loop is not just running `n` times each time it gets called, rather, it runs `n` times, then `n-1` times, then `n-2`, etc. In total, it runs `n!` times *each time it is started*. Thus, we have `n!` runs, each time doing `O(n)` work means a total of `O(n x n!)` runs once started. But, now we have only considered the number of times the `for` loop runs *each time* it is called. How many times is it actually started? Well that would be `n` times because we can see the recursion ends when `n=0`. Hence, `n x n x n!` once again.

> Now if you spot an error in my reasoning (especially with the 2nd way of thinking), please do not hesitate to point it out! I want to make sure that I am thinking about this correctly.

Comment: I worry that your analysis isn't taking into account that different calls to permutation() have different costs. All calls aren't the same. There are different *n*'s at each level of the tree.

Comment: A better and more rigorous way to analyze it is to set up a recurrence relation. Something like f(s,p) = s * (s + f(s-1,p+1)) with a base case f(0,p) = p. A closed form formula should indeed be some sort of factorial since we know it's printing permutations.

Comment: @JohnKugelman You make a valid point, I did not consider this in my analysis. I apologize for the questions but is there any way you could explain how one would arrive at the correct answer `O(n x n x n!)` using recurrence relations? Your formula makes sense to me but I am not sure how to go about actually solving it and obtaining a time complexity value from it. I looked through some lectures online but I am still a bit confused with regards to this case in particular.

Comment: I'm 15 years out of university. My mathematical chops aren't what they used to be. I can set up the problem but I'm not sure if I can solve it...

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks, I appreciate it a lot. I am just trying to figure out a standard method of approaching problems like this because when I try to reason them out, I find that occasionally I will slip up in my logic which leads to an incorrect answer.

Comment: I'm out of specific advice for this problem. There's a lot of really sloppy Big-O analysis out there, so some general advice: Always be mathematically rigorous. Define all your variables. Don't overuse *n*. It's easy to conflate different values when you call everything *n*. That's why I used *s* and *p* above -- which, to be explicit, are defined as `s = str.length()` and `p = prefix.length()`.